# Is $a \mapsto [a \cdot id]: A \to H_n(\Delta^n, \partial \Delta^n;A)$ an isomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am hoping for a problem I am working on that the function defined above is an isomorphism of groups, but I cannot manage to prove it. Is $[a \cdot \sigma] = [a \cdot id: \Delta^n \to \Delta^n]$ for any $\sigma: \Delta^n \to \Delta^n$?

Comment: How much do you know about homology so far ? Do you know that it is homotopy invariant ? and do you know the homology long exact sequence of a pair ?

Comment: @Max yes to both questions. I know what excision is and that is pretty much it. In case you mean to use that $\partial \Delta^n$ is homotopic to $S^{n - 1}$ (homology group isomorphic to $A$) , $\Delta^n$ is homotopic to a point (trivial homology group) and then use the long exact sequence to show that the connecting homomoprhism is an isomorphism between $H_n(\Delta^n, \partial \Delta^n;A)$ and $H_{n - 1}(\partial \Delta^n;A)$, is there a way to show that that is this specific isomorphism?

Comment: Do you know perhaps that simplicial homology agrees with singular homology ?

Comment: @Max afraid not

Comment: Right, well I have a full solution except for one detail : my method of proof uses an explicit generator for $H_{n-1}(\partial \Delta^n;\mathbb Z) $ and I don't see how to get that it actually generates it without using simplicial homology. In other words, I need to deal explicitly with the $\mathbb Z$-case and I need something for that. I will try to think if one can get around it

Comment: Hi, blacksmith. This question was asked earlier today in a slightly different form: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3390923/isomorphism-h-ndn-sn-1a-and-a/3391211#3391211.

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question. I'm guessing the second point is the way around simplicial homology Max was getting at.